# Should Heroku's HOST_URL var be configured to match the domain name?

Tags: url, heroku, config

Say you have set up a domain (my-domain.com) to be used for an app on Heroku (myapp.herokuapp.com). It seems to be working as intended. However, you notice when you check the heroku config, you get this:

```
HOST_URL:              myapp.herokuapp.com
```

Should you set the HOST_URL to your domain?

*This is for a ruby on rails app.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be important if you want to use _url for any links. _url will use the HOST_NAME var from the heroku config. Since I needed to use that for links within an email, I changed it with:

```
heroku config:set HOST_URL="my-domain.com"
```

Comment: Though you answer does not explain why, I've ran into the same problem and only solution I could think of was to do that. I've also searched and only reference I've found was this very post! So thanks for sharing how you dealt with this issue @KevinM .